# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Random' and 'str'

Tags: python

I'm entering a code where a word is randomly generated. But it says TypeError and that random can't be matched with string

I've tried rewriting code multiple times but it didn't work.
Code:

```
import random

from random import *

Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 
'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

LettersInWord = Random()

Points = 0

print(LettersInWord + " is number of letters in word")

for index in range(LettersInWord):
    Word = Letters[Random.random(0, 25)]

Guess = input("Enter Word You Think It Is (You will get a point everytime 
one or more of your letters match with the word. Your turn will end when 
you enter a letter that is not in the word: ")

for letter in Guess:
    if letter == letter in Word:
        Points = Points + 1
        if Guess == Word:
            print("Congratulations, you won. End program and restart to 
            try again.")

    Guess = input("Well done, try again")
```

Comment: What do you think is happening here: `print(LettersInWord + " is number of letters in word")`?

Comment: What do you want to be printed out in the print statement?

Comment: Also this part: `for index in range(LettersInWord):
    Word = Letters[Random.random(0, 25)]`

Comment: As well as this: `if letter == letter in Word:`

Comment: And this definitely does not do what you think it does: `Guess = input("Well done, try again")`

Comment: Here is what you should do; you did a good job thus far, but you have misunderstood some key points. You are not using `Random()` properly, you want a number that depicts the length of the random word (that you generate incorrectly). When you create `Word` you are just picking a letter, and overwriting `Word` each time (you may want to look into `append`ing it. Then before you loop through each `letter`  in `Guess` you can first compare to see if the `Guess == Word` and suggest a new game. The actual way you are comparing the letters in the guess and in the word is fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Random()` is a random-number *generator*, not a number itself.

```
letters_in_word = randint(1,25)  # random number between 1 and 25, inclusive
```

(Capitalized names are conventionally reserved for class names. Use snake case identifiers for ordinary variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments:

```
from random import *

Letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

while True:
    letters_in_word = randint(1,25)
    Points = 0
    Word = []
    print("{} is number of letters in word".format(letters_in_word))
    for index in range(0, letters_in_word):
        Word.append(Letters[randint(0, 25)])

    Guess = input("Press Q/q to exit or Enter Word You Think It Is (You will get a point everytime one or more of your letters match with the word. Your turn will end when you enter a letter that is not in the word: ")
    if Guess.lower() == 'q':
       break
    print(Word)
    if Guess in Word:
       Points = 100  # assuming
       print("Congratulations, you won. End program and restart to try again.\nTotal Points: {}".format(Points))
       break
    else:
      for letter in Guess:
        if letter in Word:
            Points = Points + 1

    print("Total Points: {}".format(Points))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
10 is number of letters in word
Press Q/q to exit or Enter Word You Think It Is (You will get a point everytime one or more of your letters match with the word. Your turn will end when you enter a letter that is not in the word: pak
['f', 't', 'l', 'b', 'd', 'k', 'e', 'p', 'd', 'n']
Total Points: 2
9 is number of letters in word
Press Q/q to exit or Enter Word You Think It Is (You will get a point everytime one or more of your letters match with the word. Your turn will end when you enter a letter that is not in the word: dirt
['z', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'z', 'j', 'r', 't', 'd']
Congratulations, you won. End program and restart to try again.
Total Points: 100

Process finished with exit code 0
```